# Two sliders (range)

Tags: jquery, html, slider, range

I want to create a loan calculator on my page. So I need two sliders, one for "how much you want to borrow" and second one "for how long". And combine their outputs.
Sth like (how much) + (how long) and print it as separate output.
I think I've tried everything... The best solution seem to be the jQuery, but I'm stuck there...
Please, is there a way to do it?
Thanks, Peter

Comment: are you familiar with Javascript?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions, just as yours is. It is also a place where the users are encouraged to research their problem before posting a question about it, which you clearly lack.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I've used jQuery UI in the past(http://jqueryui.com/slider/). You can put those on your page, and then write a simple script to print out the two inputs.

If you want to access the slider's value on that page, in a script just type `$('#slider').val()` to get the value. If you want to update the output when they move the slider, just write something like

```
<script>
$('#slider').change( function () { 
    $('#sliderDisplay').html( $('#slider').val());
});
</script>
```